# Cos'è una "via di fatto"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *Il contesto*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> "Per quanto riguarda il Vangelo, senz'altro le posso dire che di affermazioni contro l'esercizio del giudicare e contro i giudici ne troverà molte. Certo, non è evangelico il passare a **vie di fatto**, come diciamo noi poliziotti. [...]"

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "via di fatto"? Alla voce "fatto" dei dizionari che ho consultato non ho trovato questa locuzione. Una ricerca su Google però mi ha fatto vedere che si tratta di un'espressione abbastanza usata.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dal [Dizionario dei modi di dire del Corriere della Sera](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/V/via.shtml#5)

> **passare alle vie di fatto**
>
> *Fig.*: venire alle mani, arrivare alla rissa o comunque alle percosse, in genere dopo essersi convinti che con le parole non si è arrivati a nulla.
>
> L'espressione risale ad alcuni codici penali precedenti all'unità d'Italia, dove indicava atti generici di violenza.

Dal contesto indicato nei commenti, la frase significa che, anche se il Vangelo non parla dei giudici in termini positivi, ucciderli è comunque contrario ai suoi dettami.

Comment: La frase fa riferimento a qualcuno che sta ammazzando giudici.

Comment: Ah ops, correggo subito l'interpretazione :).